# How can I read n lines from a txt file? n is given as input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question:
Program to read first n lines from a txt file,get n as user input.
I tried this,

```
f1=open('sampletest.txt','r')
n=int(input("Enter number of lines to be read from the txt file:"))
line=f1.readlines(n)
print(line)
f1.close()
```

My txtfile contents which I named sampletest are as follows:

Tom and Jerry are cartoon characters.

Tom is a cat.

Jerry is a mouse.

They have a common friend,Spike.

Spike is a dog.

The output I get by executing my python code:
Enter number of lines to be read from the txt file:3
['Tom and Jerry are cartoon characters.\n']

How can I correct my code?I am new to coding. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In ```readlines(n)```, the ```n``` indicates the number of bytes and not the number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1=open('sampletest.txt','r')
n=int(input("Enter number of lines to be read from the txt file:"))
line = ''.join(f1.readline() for _ in range(n))
print(line)
f1.close()
```

your code not working because readlines accepts `hint` parameter instead of lines count to read